# what does it take to upload a large file on heroku?

Tags: django, http, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a video on a Django server hosted on heroku; it is not working but when uploading a picture it works. 
I am also using AWS to store my files.
Is that i am using heroku free?

Comment: AFAIK, heroku has a default network timeout of `30 sec`. So, you may need to implement/use *chunked upload* strategy